# aws-cdk TokenAuthorizer - how to pass the payload from the authorizer to the lambda for the protected endpoint?

Tags: aws-cdk

In my cdk stack I have an api endpoint that calls a lambda and that is protected by a TokenAuthorizer using a JWT, that looks like:

```
// inside my cdk Construct
 
const auth = new apiGateway.TokenAuthorizer(this, "Authorizer", {
    handler: authorizeUserLambda
});

const api = new apiGateway.RestApi(this, "ApiGateway-lambda-authorizer", {
    description: "my api"
});

const users = api.root.addResource("users");
const getUser = users.addResource("{userId}");
const getUserIntegration = new apiGateway.LambdaIntegration(getUserLambda);
getUser.addMethod("GET", getUserIntegration, {authorizer: auth});
```

And the handler for `authorizeUserLambda` itself:

```
// types removed

function generatePolicy(principalId, effect, resource) {
    const authResponse = {
        principalId,
        context: {
            stringKey: "stringval",
            numberKey: 123,
            booleanKey: true
        }
    };

    if (effect && resource) {
        return {
            ...authResponse,
            policyDocument: {
                Version: "2012-10-17",
                Statement: [
                    {
                        Action: "execute-api:Invoke",
                        Effect: effect,
                        Resource: resource
                    }
                ]
            }
        };
    }

    return authResponse;
}


export const handler = async function authorizeUser(event) {
    const jwt = event.authorizationToken?.split(" ")[1];

    try {
        if (verify(jwt, secret)) {
            return generatePolicy("user", "Allow", event.methodArn);
        }

        return generatePolicy("user", "Deny", event.methodArn);
    } catch {
        return "Error: Invalid token";
    }
};
```

This code does successfully decode the JWT and authenticate a user, but how would I pass the payload of the JWT (or anything at all from authorizer function) to the `getUserLambda` function? Do I need to create a reference to the function's output inside the Construct? The JWT payload has a userId and role inside that I want access to for lambdas like `getUser`.

Comment: hello how did you solve it?